# Eclipse plugin: How to find/parse ternary operator?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ternary-operator, eclipse-jdt

I already have several visitors implemented, e.g. for Assignments, ForStatements etc. But as it seems there is no convenient way to find ternary operators ( ? : ) in my Java projects?

So is there any other way to find ternary expressions in my project?

Comment: That bug is for Eclipse EGL Development Tools which is nothing to do with the Java Development Tools.

Comment: Oops. Okay - removed that link. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using AST, since you are refering to "visitors". In that case you can use a vistor like this:

```
new ASTVisitor() {
    @Override
    public boolean visit(ConditionalExpression node) {
        ...
        return false;
    }
}
```

A good tool to use inside of eclipse is the ASTView, which will show you the AST of any selected code in an opened editor. You can install the ASTView from this update site:
http://www.eclipse.org/jdt/ui/update-site

Comment: I already had an ASTVisitor visiting `ConditionalExpression`s. I tried it about 50 times with no success. Now that you proposed using it, I retried running my already existing code - and it works! I don't know why, I don't know how - but that doesn't matter. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can ctrl-f, check Regular Expression, and search for:

```
\?.*:
```

Comment: I don't want to find ternary operators manually, but automatically (programmatically) inside my plugin environment. Thus I cannot use ctrl+f. Also, your regex will also bring up Strings like "Hello? I mean: Of course!"...

Comment: Why would you have "Hello? I mean: Of course!" in your code?  
I suppose another problem is it finding a "?" somewhere in the code, and a ":" in a completely different place.

Also, I misunderstood the question pretty badly, didn't I.